# Problema con el directorio config en Laravel

Tags: laravel, blade, configuración, variables-de-configuración

Tengo un archivo que he creado, con el nombre `available_languages.php`. Este archivo está en el directorio `/config`, y su contenido es el siguiente:

```
<?php
    return [
        'idiomas_disponibles' => [
            'ca' => [
                'code' => 'ca',
                'variable_name' => 'Catalán',
                'image_name' => 'ca.jpg',
            ],
            'da' => [
                'code' => 'da',
                'variable_name' => 'Danés',
                'image_name' => 'da.jpg',
            ],
            'de' => [
                'code' => 'de',
                'variable_name' => 'Alemán',
                'image_name' => 'de.jpg',
            ],
            'en' => [
                'code' => 'en',
                'variable_name' => 'Inglés',
                'image_name' => 'en.jpg',
            ],
            'es' => [
                'code' => 'es',
                'variable_name' => 'Español',
                'image_name' => 'es.jpg',
            ],
            'eu' => [
                'code' => 'eu',
                'variable_name' => 'Euskera',
                'image_name' => 'eu.jpg',
            ],
            'fr' => [
                'code' => 'fr',
                'variable_name' => 'Francés',
                'image_name' => 'fr.jpg',
            ],
            'pt' => [
                'code' => 'pt',
                'variable_name' => 'Portugués',
                'image_name' => 'pt.jpg',
            ],
            'it' => [
                'code' => 'it',
                'variable_name' => 'Italiano',
                'image_name' => 'it.jpg',
            ],
            'ro' => [
                'code' => 'ro',
                'variable_name' => 'Rumano',
                'image_name' => 'ro.jpg',
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

Se supone que los archivos contenidos en `/config` se cargan al arranque de la aplicación, y están disponibles en cualquier parte, durante todo el ciclo de uso.

El problema es que intento usar la matriz `$idiomas_disponibles` en una vista, y no me la encuentra, me da un error porque "no existe". Primero intenté usarla así:

```
@foreach($idiomas_disponibles as $idioma_disponible)
```

Como no funciono, he intentado el helper `config()`, así:

```
@foreach(config($idiomas_disponibles) as $idioma_disponible)
```

Tampoco la reconoce, pero al ser datos que están en `/config`, debería poder leerlos, no?

Debo añadir que, antes de cada prueba he tecleado, en la consola lo siguiente:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Lo hice por si estaba la configuración anterior cacheada. Tampoco me ha dado resultado.

Comment: Intenta usar el [*facade* `Config`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Config/Repository.html) para ello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes acceder de la siguiente manera, según la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#accessing-configuration-values):

```
config('available_languages.idiomas_disponibles');
```

Comment: Gracias, me ofusqué y no vi esa parte. :-)